# XDSoft datetimepicker - how to set date via javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there setDate method to set user selected date via javascript dynamically after calendar init?
I have to simulate user select date.

JS library - https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery to change the input value that you are using the date picker widget on. By default, the library uses the standard US date/time layout.

```
$("#selector-to-taken-over-element").val("2019/12/4");
```

You can also change it directly using the DateTimePicker function:

```
 $("#selector-to-taken-over-element").datetimepicker({
   value: "2019/12/4"
 });
```

For more options, visit the datetimepicker [Full Options List documenation](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#value)